# How to IMPORT keyboard shortcuts in Adobe Dreamweaver

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver

I recently upgraded to Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.

I have backup my CS5 keyboard shortcuts into a "dreamweaver shortcut.htm" file from the Edit Menu > Keyboard Shortcuts option but I am just not able to find an import option in cs6 or any of the old dreamweaver versions as well to import my old shortcuts into the new version.

If anybody knows the import method for keyboard shortcut in Dreamweaver please let me know.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me in Win7:
(Replace [your_profile] with the name you use to log in to this machine. If you're not using the English-language version, you'll need to change en_US to your local variant too.)

Go to:

> C:\Users[your_profile]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CS5\en_US\Configuration\Menus\Custom Sets

You should find two files there:
active **set.txt** (which just contains the name of the keyboard shortcut set you were using)
and the xml file containing your lovingly crafted shortcuts.

Copy the xml file (or both of them, if you wish, in which case CS6 will start with this set) to:

> C:\Users[your_profile]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CS6\en_US\Configuration\Menus\Custom Sets

Comment: Great Answer Steve !! Nice finding. I can happily remove the answer vote which I voted to myself and I can accept yours now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Adobe doesn't provide an option to import the exported keyboard shortcuts back.

I got the following lines from one of Adobe resource for creative cloud from which I assume that there isn't any inbuilt command provided by Dreamweaver to import the shortcuts back but to manually do it.

```
Export keyboard shortcuts
Before upgrading to Creative Cloud, do the following:
1.  Select Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts
2.  Click "Export Set As HTML" button.
After you upgrade, refer to the exported file to set the shortcuts again.
```

[Reference - http://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/dreamweaver_reference.pdf](http://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/dreamweaver_reference.pdf)